# GoogleMap : Count the amount of markers of each type and instantly update the result when i add new marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this code that allows me to add markers of different types on a map by drag'n'droppping them into the map.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <title>TEST1</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
            }
            html { height: 100% }
            body{ height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
            #map_canvas { height: 80% ; width:70%;clear:none}
            #shelf{position:relative; top:10px; height:20%;width:100%;background:white;opacity:0.7;}
            #draggable {position:absolute; top:15px;left:50px; width: 30px; height: 50px;z-index:1000000000;}
        </style>
        <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $("#draggable1").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e,ui) {
                        var mOffset=$($map.getDiv()).offset();
                            var point=new google.maps.Point(
                                ui.offset.left-mOffset.left+(ui.helper.width()/2),
                                ui.offset.top-mOffset.top+(ui.helper.height())
                        );
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });
                $("#draggable2").draggable({helper: 'clone',
                    stop: function(e,ui) {
                        var mOffset=$($map.getDiv()).offset();
                            var point=new google.maps.Point(
                                ui.offset.left-mOffset.left+(ui.helper.width()/2),
                                ui.offset.top-mOffset.top+(ui.helper.height())
                        );
                        var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
                        var icon = $(this).attr('src');
                        placeMarker(ll, icon);
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var $map;
            var $latlng;
            var overlay;

            function initialize() {
                var $latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5833, 5.8667);
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 18,
                    center: $latlng,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                    mapTypeControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT },
                    zoomControl: true,
                    zoomControlOptions: {
                        style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
                    },
                    scaleControl: true,
                    scaleControlOptions: {
                        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
                    },
                    streetViewControl: false,

                    panControl:false,

                };
                $map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                myOptions);

                overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
                overlay.draw = function() {};
                overlay.setMap($map);


            } 
            function placeMarker(location, icon) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location, 
                    map: $map,
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: icon
                });

            }

            function countMarkers(markers) {
            var count = 0;
            $.each(markers, function (i, marker) {
            console.log(marker.visible);
            if (marker.visible == true) {
            count++;
            }
            });
            $('#countBox').val(count);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>
        <div id='shelf'>
        <img src="spring-hot.png" id="draggable1" />Total : X<br><img src="spring-cold.png" id="draggable2" />Total : Y
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

I'd like to show next to each marker type under my map **the total amount** of markers of this type on the map, and **automatically update** this total amount everytime i **add a new marker** to my map.

I suppose it could be easy to do it but i really dont find how to !

Could you please help me ?

Comment: What approaches have you tried so far to find the number of markers?

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping two arrays, one for each type of marker (eg var markerType1 = []; markerType2=[]`). Then instead of just calling the placeMarker function, push the new marker into the appropriate array by doing markerType1.push(placeMarker(ll, icon)).

Then change your placeMarker function to return the new marker like so

```
return  new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: location, 
                    map: $map,
                    draggable: true,
                    icon: icon
                });
```

Then you can just use the array lengths to count the markers:

```
markerType1.length
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately i don't understand...
I'm just a beginner and i don't even know what is an array...
I made this code by compiling different fragments of codes i found on the web, but i'm not specialized enough... so i guess i should learn more about javascript before trying to do it...